# SQL - Como selecionar ou excluir uma uma coluna com valor igual a null numa query select

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Eu tenho uma tabela num bd MySQL que possui 5 campos.
Essa seria uma query modelo:

```
select * from myTable where campo1= 4 and campo2=1 and campo3 =7.
```

Porém o campo3 pode possuir valor null e eu precisaria selecionar ou excluir combinações que envolvam esse valor.

Exemplo1:

```
select * from myTable where campo1= 4 and campo2=1 and campo3 = null.
```

Exemplo2:

```
select * from myTable where campo1= 4 and campo2=1 and campo3 <> null.
```

O problema é que esses dois exemplos não funcionam.
Já tentei usar `"null"` e `'null'` mas não consigo selecionar.

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de usar `campo = null` tente fazer dessa forma:

```
WHERE campo IS NULL
```

No `Mysql` o essa expressão testa se o campo é `null`. Para fazer o inverso é só usar o `IS NOT NULL`.

[Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb840b/5)

Answer (score 3):

No caso de o `campo3 = null` e nao o querer mostrar:

```
select * from myTable where campo1= 4 and campo2=1 where campo3 is not null
```

No caso de querer mostrar apenas quando o `campo3<>null`:

```
select * from myTable where campo1= 4 and campo2=1 where campo3 is null
```